# Suggest the regex for this pattern

Tags: java, regex

Hi how to split the below text based on the pattern

1. More than one space
2. followed by the word starting with capital letter

Sample text:

```
Overview  This is my sample program      Written in java
```

Required output

```
Overview
This is my sample program
Written in java
```

I have tried the below regex but not working

```
"\\s{2,}\\[A-z]"
```

Please suggest me a regex to split my text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use positive look forward (`(?=[A-Z])`) to match uppercase alphabet without consuming:

```
String text = "Overview  This is my sample program      Written in java";
String[] words = text.split("\\s{2,}(?=[A-Z])");
for (String word : words)
    System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "Overview  This is my sample program      Written in java";
    String[] words = text.split("\\s{2,}");
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

You don't have to use positive look forward.

Comment: OP specified "followed by the word starting with capital letter"